# Run dart code continusously on save in VScode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am new to dart.

I have configured, dart + flutter + vscode etc. In the vscode i am able to run .dart file through Debug panel.

What I want it to run the program on file save. Just like I do in node.js using nodemon package. it watches the files save and rerun the app.

Is something like this possible in VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/49209#issuecomment-675101308) looks promising. He modified [Save and Run Ext](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=padjon.save-and-run-ext) plugin for VS Code

Answer (score 0):

Go to Vs code settings

next type `flutter hot` on search box.
then select these two options

[image: flutter hot reload]

Comment: thanks, but these setting already selected, so how can i continuously get the print output in terminal. Is there any command to run in terminal?

Comment: are you tring to run dart file or flutter application?

Comment: for dart you can use : dart run path_to_file/file    and for flutter : flutter run path_to_folder_containing_pubspec